# Moderators abusing rules

Tags: support, moderation

What were the reasons of my ban from SU, MSU (for a period of 1 **month**)? and extension of ban in SO from 7 days **to a month** without any warning and notification?

- ["A Day in Penalty Box"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box) tells:

> If a moderator has warned you via
>   email about behavior, and that
>   behavior continues, for a period of 2
>   to 7 days, your account will be in
>   timed suspension

I had never been warned through Email.
I also did not continue (what had I continued and where)?

As a matter of fact, I even do not know what had I infringed this time

Comment: Arguing about your bans is not helping you at all.  If you are really interested in learning then don't start with an accusation like 'moderators abusing rules'.

Comment: I am not arguing. I am just really bewildered what you are up to with it?

Comment: your tone is consistently accusatory. Zoredache isn't even a moderator, yet you just specifically called him out with "what *you* are up to". It's become extraordinarily obvious you have plenty of learning to do, but you rarely approach these opportunities with an open mind/attitude. We don't take issue with what you say nearly as much as how you say it.

Comment: @Chris S, not being moderator did not stop Zoredache from closing and delete quite a lot of my posts. If she does not have any influence on things then why to interfere at all?

Comment: He cannot close or delete anything by himself. Closing requires 5 non-moderator votes from users over 3000 rep and deleting closed questions takes 5 non-moderator votes from users over 10,000 rep.

Answer (score 11):

Not only did you receive the email notifying you that/why you were being suspended, you responded to it.  Perhaps you've forgotten and misplaced this email, it was dated:  Fri, Aug 13, 2010 at 6:20 PM

It was all very straightforward.

You seem to forget all warnings, instructions, and assistance communicated to you.  I am deeply sympathetic if this is the result of difficulties with English - but if you continue to create disruptive meta-discussion on ServerFault itself, we'll have no choice but to ban you for the sake of the community at large.

The best thing you can do at this point is forget trying to fight the suspension, move on, and try very hard to avoid posting things that will cause the community to flag them for moderator action.

Comment: I asked about new bans from 08/22 and you are telling me about Email from 08/13. I insist that there was not a single Email with warning or notification about new bans and extension of old ones.

Comment: Even more, my Email to team@xxxx.com had not got a single answer. BTW, I had no discussions AT ALL in SO, why the ban for month duration there?

Comment: @vgv8, you'll have to ask the SO team about the ban there; the sites have separate moderators.

Comment: @Chris_S, how to ask if I am banned from MSO and team@stackoverflow.com had never responded even once. I have feeling that it is a black hole dump Email.

Comment: @vgv8 - Perhaps you should take the hint?

Comment: @vgv8 team@stackoverflow is most certainly not a black hole.  I've received a reply to each message that I've sent over to them, usually within an hour or two of sending.  Your account is not (currently) suspended on MSO.  You can post there, but I highly recommend keeping it to an email with the team at this point.  If you have not received a response then try again, and be civil in your communication with them.

Comment: @squillman, And I do not have any response from team@stackoverflow in 3 weeks. I had never been notifies about new suspensions. I